# Some video file fails to play in windows phone 7.5

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing a windows phone App(Mango 7.5). when trying to play a video file (.wmv) through web browser, getting this error "Sorry, we can't play this file on your phone".

Please let me know if there is a fix for this. File size is around16 MB. 
The issue raises only for few files, and not for all .wmv files. 
Please provide your inputs on this to resolve it.

I tried the fix provided using MediaPlayerLauncherstill could not resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not all WMV files are exactly compatible with all WMV players. Can you re-code the movie with another software package and try it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [list of media codecs supported by Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462087%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). Even on the latest types of processors, support is limited to 800x600 resolution and 2Mbps average bitrate, so it won't be able to play HD videos encoded in WMV for instance.